# Google Sheets API Timeout

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I made a script that write to rows in a google sheets using the google sheets API. After a while of running and working perfectly, it will give me a 401 error:

> code: 401,
>   message: "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
>   status: "UNAUTHENTICATED"

I'm assuming its just timing me out for a while but I am not sure. Is there a way to prevent it from giving me this error.

Comment: Can you provide the script for replicating the error? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to authenticate and connect, identify which line is causing the error and edit your question tags to contain the correct API library language. Make sure to sanitise your auth code before posting.